# Why does a bur overheat when isn't moving fast enough?

Tags: thermodynamics

When milling wood, if the bur is spinning fast but not moving through the wood fast enough, the bur will heat and the wood will start to char. One way to avoid charring the wood is to increase the speed at which the bur is moving through the wood. This is explained (in French) [here](https://www.cncfraises.fr/content/19-fraisage-du-bois-fraise-carbure-cnc).

Increasing speed to decrease heating seems rather counterintuitive to me, so I wanted to know what the physical process is that causes the bur to heat in this case.

Comment: The wood is not charring due to heat. It is charring due to friction work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to look up what a [bur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_(cutter)) is .

It is a matter of conservation of energy. When the rotational momentum given by the tool to the burr is not enough to overcome the molecular resistance of the material, the energy given to the rotation goes into heating the burr, which heat can burn a wooden object you are trying to pierce.

If you increase the rotational energy you give to the burr, the added rotational momentum can overcome the resistance of the lattice of  molecules of the wood, and pierce it as it rotates  , the extra energy going into the rotational motion of the burr through the wood, and the falling pieces.

> to increase the speed at which the bur is moving through the wood

increasing the push on the burr, once the molecular lattice is broken, allows for faster distribution of energy going into kinetic energy of breaking pieces instead of to  heat.

Answer (score 1):

If you to not *load* the rotating burr *into* the workpiece, the teeth on the burr will not cut into and penetrate the workpiece and thereby slice off a shaving of it, but instead will just spin around and scuff the surface. That scuffing action generates frictional heat which chars the workpiece and heats up the burr, and the workpiece throws smoke- and may start on fire.